# What is Robot Army Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, model-based-testing

What is Robot Army Testing? Where is it used? How can I learn it?

Comment: I've never heard of it, but it sounds AWESOME.

Comment: Unfortunately it is nothing to do with training battalions of armoured automata to conquer the world :(

Comment: Curses. ***extranonsensetomakesohappy***

Comment: Me too. If it doesn't exist, it needs to, and soon!

Comment: -1 to APC - For dashing our hopes. :(

Comment: Well, it it doesn't exist now, it will soon. Congratulations on being the inspiration for an idea.

Comment: @mlk - My hopes were dashed too!

Comment: Robot Army Testing exists and its one of model based testing ....

Comment: and its introduced by Harry Robinson from Google .

Comment: Check here more about Robot Army Testing :http://www.geocities.com/model_based_testing/intelligent.pdf

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure that it exists.  There's Rational Robot, an automated testing record-and-playback tool, but you have to buy it.  I've yet to hear of Robot Army testing, however, although I agree with Nick - it sounds AWESOME :)

The only mention I can find of it ANYWHERE is on:

http://www.mail-archive.com/wtr-general@rubyforge.org/msg07756.html

So maybe it's also known as MBT (Model Based Testing)?

If so, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-based_testing for information on that and some handy links to tutorials etc.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

If by "Robot Army Testing" you mean assembling a suite of automated tests on a grand scale (sort of xUnit on steroids) then [this presentation](http://model.based.testing.googlepages.com/How-to-Build-Your-Own-Robot-Army.pdf) provides a helpful introduction.  It is also known as Model-Based Testing.

**edit**

As uberRouse notes, the use of randomly generated values in testing is interesting.  I first came across this in 2005.  It was a tool called Agitator [from Agitar Software](http://www.agitar.com/) which took manually written unit tests and expanded on the coverage by plugging in random values and edge cases.

Comment: Cool presentation. Thanks for the link. I hope you get all the points

Comment: That basically is just Automated Testing and the pros of it.  It doesn't mention the cons (well apart from forgetting about actually testing).  Mildly frustrating with all these buzz names sometimes eh :)  Good presentation tho - the bugs found with random input - that stat was just scary!

Answer (score 2):

This term is not on WikiPedia. Everything, that is at least a little popular technology appears there quickly. Are you sure you don't misspell it?

Comment: It can. But being at least a little popular, I will no doubt appear on WikiPedia quickly enough.

Comment: But only until it gets deleted for being 'not notable' by the deletion brigade.

Comment: I doubt they delete useful things from it. And if it is useful, soon after deletion it will reappear. If it will be deleted again, someone will open a debate. And this will end up in either adding it to pedia, or dropping it as having no a right to exist ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Robot Framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) maybe? We use it and it's great!

Comment: +1 for the link.  It's intriguing and also slightly sinister that Google is behind all this Robot Testing stuff, because they are set on world domination....

Answer (score 0):

BTW, it sounds like web-site DDOS testing ;)